# update manager gives unmet dependency error

Tags: updates, dpkg, dependencies

Can anyone please help me to solve the issue?

While updating update manager gives the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

**libqt4-declarative:** 
Depends: libqt4-network (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.8) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.8 is installed
Depends: libqt4-script (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.8) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.8 is installed
Depends: libqt4-sql (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.8) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.8 is installed
Depends: libqt4-xmlpatterns (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.8) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.8 is installed
Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.8) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.8 is installed
Depends: libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.8) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.8 is installed

**libqt4-declarative:i386:** 
Depends: libqt4-network (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.6) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.8 is installed
Depends: libqt4-script (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.6) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.8 is installed
Depends: libqt4-sql (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.6) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.8 is installed
Depends: libqt4-xmlpatterns (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.6) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.8 is installed
Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.6) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.8 is installed
Depends: libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.6) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.8 is installed

****libqt4-opengl:****
Depends: libgl1 but it is a virtual package
Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.6) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.8 is installed
Depends: libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.6) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.8 is installed

**libqt4-svg:** 
Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.6) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.8 is installed
Depends: libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.6) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.8 is installed

**libqtgui4:i386:** 
Depends: libqt4-declarative (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.8) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.8 is installed
Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.8) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.8 is installed
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you are missing one of the canonical repositories so will you please launch *Software Sources* and under *Ubuntu Software* tab make sure it is set similar to:

[image]

After changing setting make sure you run `sudo apt-get update`. You are then ready to retry the installation / update.